# Buy tokens form other smart contract using interface

Tags: solidity, tokens, ether, interfaces

I have two separate contracts, let's say `Token` and `BuyFrom`.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

interface InterfaceToken {
    function invest(address contributor) external payable;
}

contract Token {
    string public name = "Token";
    string public symbol = "TKN";
    uint public decimals = 0;
    uint tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;

    uint public supply;
    address public founder;
    address payable public deposit;

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    constructor(address payable _deposit, address _founder) public{
        supply = 300000;
        deposit = _deposit;
        founder = _founder;
        balances[founder] = supply;
    }

    function invest(address contributor) public payable {
        uint tokens = msg.value / tokenPrice;

        balances[contributor] += tokens;
        balances[founder] -= tokens;

        deposit.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

I want to buy tokens from `BuyFrom` using an interface. But it doesn't work.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;

import 'Token.sol';

contract BuyFrom {
    address payable private token;

    constructor(address payable _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function buyToken(address contributor) external payable {
       InterfaceToken(token).invest(contributor);
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `InterfaceToken(token).invest` is an external call (i.e., to a function in another contract), you need to pass along the value that your function has received.

In other words, change this:

```
InterfaceToken(token).invest(contributor);
```

To this:

```
InterfaceToken(token).invest.value(msg.value)(contributor);
```